# How to implement a simple stride predictor?

Tags: prediction, hybrid, markov, stride

I have implemented a contextual `Markov predictor` and I need to make a `stride predictor` to combine them into a `hybrid predictor` with confidence.
For the beginning I need to implement this `stride predictor`. I read about it and I found this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf0Td.png) but I want to make it simpler.
The classic formula is `Vn=V(n-1)+(V(n-1)-V(n-2))` and I thought at something like having 2 variables `difference1` which is equal with `V(n-1)-V(n-2)` and `difference2` which is equal with `V(n-2)-V(n-3)` and then compare them and if they are equal then `Vn=V(n-1)+difference1`.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a need to change the classic formula.

The reasoning behind it is that you only need to know two variables and you can make the assumption. And in fact, you *make* the assumption every time, not just in case the stride is the same as the previous stride.

The predictor has three states it operates in:

**initial** - when there is no information about the stride

**transient** - there is a stride between the previous value and the current value of the variable

**steady** - the previous prediction was correct

I guess the state transitions are self-explanatory, but just in case:

initial -> transient occurs when the variable assumes new value
transient -> steady occurs when the prediction using the stride calculated when predictor moved to transient state was correct
steady -> transient occurs when the prediction using the stride was incorrect, and the new stride becomes the active stride